# Get Map<String, Integer> with Gson

Tags: android, gson

I have this simple json response from a server.

```
{
   "string 1": 5,
   "string 2": 42,
    ... many more ...
}
```

How can I de-serialize this response and get a `Map<String, Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too easy! I really like gson <3

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = gson.fromJson(s, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Integer>>(){}.getType());
```